# How to delete posts with incorrect status

Tags: posts, automation

This is a weird one. By mistake, I created some posts using WP Webhooks + Make where the post_status was incorrectly set to "published" instead of "publish".

Now, for some reason that action wasn't rejected, and the posts were somehow created. 4 of them.
The funny thing is that they're not visible through the dashboard in any way. You can see it counts them in "All" but you cannot make them appear in there, as I guess they are not being recognized as proper posts.

I also tried to make a Webhook call to delete the posts by ID, since I have their ID based on the automation report. But it just says the post doesn't exist, which is weird.

Any idea how to find them and how to properly clean them?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do it directly via the DB? Use WP-CLI?

Comment: Not super familiar with CLI. And I believe deleting just the post table items is not a great practice...